# Adding an event listener to a list element contained within a <ul> in a popup menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension where you are able to enter data into an input box the popup menu. This data should be saved and show up every time you launch the popup menu. You should be able to remove data from the list by clicking the element. I have been able to figure out how to store the data points but I am having trouble deleting it.
Here's the popup.js

```js
// global variables
var urlList=[];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getUrlListAndRestoreInDom();
    // event listener for pressing enter
    var input = document.getElementById('url');
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
   workTab = input.value;
    if (workTab.length>0 && urlList.indexOf(workTab) === -1){
     addUrlToListAndSave(workTab);
              addUrlToDom(workTab);
    } 
    input.value ="";
   } 
  }); 
});
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(click){
  click.addEventListener("click",function(){
   alert(this.id);
   console.log(document)  
  })
 });

    
function getUrlListAndRestoreInDom(){
    chrome.storage.local.get({urlList:[]},function(data){
        urlList = data.urlList;
        urlList.forEach(function(url){
            addUrlToDom(url);
        });
    });
}

function addUrlToDom(url){
    var newLine = document.createElement('li');
    newLine.textContent = url;
    newLine.setAttribute("id", url);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newLine);
}

function addUrlToListAndSave(url){
    if(urlList.indexOf(url) === -1){
        //URL is not already in list
        urlList.push(url);
        saveUrlList();
    }
}
function removeUrlAndSave(url){
 myarray.splice($.inArray(url, urlList), 1);
 saveUrlList();
}

function saveUrlList(callback){
    chrome.storage.local.set({urlList},function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            //If there was no callback provided, don't try to call it.
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's the popup.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <input type="url" id ="url" placeholder="timetowork.com">
  <ul id = "list">
   <li id="google">google</li>
         <li id="bbc">bbc</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am trying to trigger an event when the user clicks on the data point. What ends up happening is that if the list element was already in the original HTML file, it triggers. Otherwise, if it was added in through the input box, it doesn't.

Comment: you need to add an eventlistener to the li element when you create it

Comment: have you looked into jquery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)? this might help you to solve the issue.

Comment: @thegunmaster jQuery `delegate` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your event listeners when the page first loads, so I'm guessing not adding them to the generated fields.  This section

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(click){
    click.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert(this.id);
        console.log(document)       
    })
});
```

needs to be run after the fields are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are adding `<li>` elements under your `<ul>` after you have added your event listeners. Thus, the new elements have no `click` event listener assigned. There are two methods of solving this:

1. Add an event listener to each element as you add it.
2. Use what is called event delegation. This is adding the event listener on an ancestor element of those you are interested in and then only performing the action if the `event.target` matches the criteria for the elements you desire to do something with.

   In this case, the simplest way is by adding one event listener to the `<ul>` and then only do something if the `event.target` is a `<li>`. Thus, adding your `click` event listener could change to:

   ```
   document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener("click",function(event){
       if(event.target.nodeName !=='LI') {
           return;
       }
       alert(event.target.id);
       //Way too much information:
       //console.log(document)     
   });
   ```

### A snippet to demonstrate the change

Below is a snippet which demonstrates that the code is operational with just the change mentioned above.

There is some additional code in the HTML which fakes `chrome.storage.local` for use in this snippet. None of the changes to the HTML should be applied to your extension. They were *only* for demonstrating this in a snippet.

I did not add code to remove the clicked `<li>`, as that was not actually part of your question.

```js
// global variables
var urlList=[];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getUrlListAndRestoreInDom();
    // event listener for pressing enter
    var input = document.getElementById('url');
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            workTab = input.value;
            if (workTab.length>0 && urlList.indexOf(workTab) === -1){
                addUrlToListAndSave(workTab);
                addUrlToDom(workTab);
            } 
            input.value ="";
        } 
    }); 
});
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener("click",function(event){
    if(event.target.nodeName !=='LI') {
        return;
    }
    alert(event.target.id);
    //Way too much information:
    //console.log(document)  
});
    
function getUrlListAndRestoreInDom(){
    chrome.storage.local.get({urlList:[]},function(data){
        urlList = data.urlList;
        urlList.forEach(function(url){
            addUrlToDom(url);
        });
    });
}

function addUrlToDom(url){
    var newLine = document.createElement('li');
    newLine.textContent = url;
    newLine.setAttribute("id", url);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newLine);
}

function addUrlToListAndSave(url){
    if(urlList.indexOf(url) === -1){
        //URL is not already in list
        urlList.push(url);
        saveUrlList();
    }
}
function removeUrlAndSave(url){
    myarray.splice($.inArray(url, urlList), 1);
    saveUrlList();
}

function saveUrlList(callback){
    chrome.storage.local.set({urlList},function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            //If there was no callback provided, don't try to call it.
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--You need the following line, but for faking this in a snippet, it is commented out
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
-->
  <!-- Fake Chrome storage.local DON'T PUT THIS IN YOUR Chrome extension it is only
         for testing in a Stack Overflow snippet.-->
  <script>
    var chrome = {
      storage: {
        local: {
          storage:{},
          set: function(obj,callback){
            //This properly stores things that the real API does not.
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop=>{
              chrome.storage.local.storage[prop] = JSON.stringify(obj[prop]);
            });
            if(typeof callback === 'function') callback();
          },
          get: function(arg1,callback){
            let output={};
            let obj = typeof arg1 === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arg1) && arg1 !== null?arg1:{};
            props = typeof arg1 === 'string'?[arg1]:Array.isArray(arg1)?arg1:arg1 === null?Object.keys(chrome.storage.local.storage):Object.keys(arg1);
            props.forEach(prop=>{
              output[prop]= typeof chrome.storage.local.storage[prop] !== 'undefined'?JSON.parse(chrome.storage.local.storage[prop]):obj[prop];
            });
            if(typeof callback === 'function') callback(output);
          }
        }
      }
    };
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <input type="url" id ="url" placeholder="timetowork.com"> &nbsp;←&nbsp;Enter a URL to add it to the list. Below, click to alert that item:
  <ul id = "list">
   <li id="google">google</li>
         <li id="bbc">bbc</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
<!--You need the following 2 lines, but for faking this in a snippet, they are commented out
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
-->

</html>
```